# Hibernate configuration error while reading schema

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jboss, jboss-tools

**Hey stackoverflow**,

I tried to add a Hibernate configuration to my workspace in order to reverse engineer my database.
When I am opening the database point in the 'Hibernate Configurations' view, i get a `Reading schema error: null` with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$1.compare(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:76)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.toArray(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:75)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:74)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:238)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Has someone experienced this before?
I am running a fresh installation of Eclipse Luna / Newest JBoss Tools and trying to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.3 DB.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

My `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://10.244.7.77:5432/netview</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I just realized, if i add a default schema `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">` it works, but just for this schema.

**EDIT 3:**

It works with an old version of Hibernate tools (3.6.0.M1-v20120827-0757-H1125). Now i am confused.

Comment: Show us your configuration file. Also, what do you mean by 'reverse my database'?

Comment: Oh, sorry for my imprecision. I ment use the Hibernate RevEng tool.

Comment: I get this same error with an Oracle database. Putting `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">MY_USER</property>` sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out that it might be a bug in JBoss Tools. So I opened a ticket: https://issues.jboss.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JBIDE-19830

Answer (score 0):

Try out this config:

```
<!-- Database connection settings -->
```

org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
postgres
password

1

org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

thread

org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider

true

```html
Try out this config:
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

 </session-factory>
```

Comment: Is it giving the same/previous error or some new ones?

Comment: Same ones / didn't change anything... Could you edit your Answer for better appeareance of xml code please?

Comment: Thank you. It didn't change anything.